# Android studio adds wrong xcodeproj location in KMP/KMM/KN

Tags: android-studio, kotlin-multiplatform, kotlin-multiplatform-mobile

I'm trying to run both a brand new KMM application, and an existing KMM application I had created before, and when I try to run the iOS version out of Android Studio I don't have an iOS configuration.

[image]

When I go create an iOS configuration I get an error that must be fixed first. When I push on "fix it" button, the `gradle.properties` file creates a new line of `xcodeproj=iosApp/iosApp.xcodeproj`

This is both wrong, and duplicated.

[image]

[image]

If I remove either of the duplicated `xcodeproj` lines, the error continues and I get a new line when I fix it (again).
If you repeat this process you can also end up with many of the new `xcodeproj` lines, all with the wrong location.
Modifying the location to the correct location also doesn't solve the problem.

[image]

Any thoughts? Seems like a bug in Android Studio 4.1.2.

Here are the details of the Android Studio version:

Android Studio 4.1.2
Build #AI-201.8743.12.41.7042882, built on December 19, 2020
Runtime version: 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b3-6915495 x86_64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
macOS 10.15.7
GC: ParNew, ConcurrentMarkSweep
Memory: 1979M
Cores: 12
Registry: ide.new.welcome.screen.force=true, external.system.auto.import.disabled=true, debugger.watches.in.variables=false
Non-Bundled Plugins: com.intellij.lang.jsgraphql, org.jetbrains.kotlin, com.jetbrains.kmm

Comment: Hi I just tried running a new and old KMM application in A.S - 4.1.2 and it did worked fine for me. 
Also from the screenshot you have posted I can see that for iOS App scheme has not been selected can you please check if you have scheme named `iosApp` in the drop down list. 
I don't see any wrong in the `gradle.properties` file.

Comment: I tried to reproduce it locally, but with no luck. What are your Kotlin and KMM plugin versions?

Comment: KMM version: `0.2.0-release-65-Studio4.1`. Kotlin version: `1.4.30-release-Studio4.1-1`.
Android Studio 4.2 Beta 4 works though

Comment: versions are also the same which I used did you get `iosApp` in the dropdown ?

Comment: nope. no ios in any dropdown due to error that cannot be fixed (and duplicates itself)

Comment: Which version of Xcode are you using also can you please check if you have set `Command Line Tools` in your Xcode ? You can check from :- `Xcode -> Preferences -> Locations -> Command Line tools`

Comment: Try this :- https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-44805

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to configure an iOS Application for Kotlin Multiplatform in Android Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66117869/how-to-configure-an-ios-application-for-kotlin-multiplatform-in-android-studio)

Comment: i gave up, but thanks for reaching out though