# Kotlin Multiplatform Mobile - Issue while running ios app from Android studio

Tags: android-studio, kotlin-multiplatform, kmm

I'm exploring KMM, I have done with the setup in Android Studio. I could able to run the Android app perfectly, but when I try to run the ios app, facing an issue in configuration setup. Xcode project scheme Dropdown is empty. I have attached a screenshot for reference.

- Android Studio v4.1.2
- Xcode 11.4
- Mac OS 10.15.4
- Kotlin plugin version
  1.4.20.

**Note:**

- I tried specifying the Xcode project location. But no luck.
- But when I launch the ios App directly from Xcode, the app is working perfectly.

[image]

Comment: maybe this can help :- https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-41691

Comment: duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66055014/android-studio-adds-wrong-xcodeproj-location-in-kmp-kmm-kn and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66113448/kotlin-multiplatform-mobile-unable-to-run-on-ios-execution-failed-for-task-sh#comment116896069_66113448 but no solution yet.

Comment: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-44805 Try this

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to configure an iOS Application for Kotlin Multiplatform in Android Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66117869/how-to-configure-an-ios-application-for-kotlin-multiplatform-in-android-studio)

Comment: There is a plugin for that in Android Studio called Kotlin Multiplatform Mobile. With it you should be able to open iOS app from AS

Answer (score 0):

For your Kotlin version, the KMM plugin version should be 0.2.0 in accord with this release page https://kotlinlang.org/docs/mobile/kmm-plugin-releases.html#release-details.

I solved using Kotlin v1.5.0 e KMM v0.2.4.